# Lint error "Literal '+' appeared as a condition" when using ternary if

Tags: ruby, rubocop

I have some code. It should remove a trailing `+` from a string if present:

```
def remove_prefix(number)
  number.start_with? '+' ? number[1..-1] : number
end
```

But it doesn't work as expected – it just returns `false`:

```
remove_prefix('123')  #=> false
remove_prefix('+123') #=> false
```

Rubocop shows this error:

> Lint/LiteralAsCondition: Literal '+' appeared as a condition.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you test the code?

Comment: Yes... And my method return Boolean, but I expected String value.

Comment: FYI: [`String#delete_prefix`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-delete_prefix)

Answer (score 3):

bad: `number.start_with? '+' ? number[1..-1] : number`
good: `number.start_with?('+') ? number[1..-1] : number`

Comment: ...because the former is equivalent to `number.start_with?('+' ? number[1..-1] : number)`. Where `+` is a literal in a conditional `?:`. So Rubocop is thinking, you already know it's truthy, so you might as well have written `number[1..-1]` instead `'+' ? number[1..-1] : number`. Obviously, you have the wrong conditional in the first place, due to parenthesis-less syntax.

Comment: @SergeyBlohin you might want to add some explanation as to _why_ the former is "bad" and the latter is "good" (see Amadan's comment). Both, in regard to the Rubocop warning and the expected result.